# Google Chart - Populate with JSON

Tags: json, servlets, charts

I have been trying to fill my Google chart dynamicly, like this example:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

I'm using this dependency for the DataTable class and others:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.visualization</groupId>
    <artifactId>visualization-datasource</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the API for the DataTable class:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_javadocs/com/google/visualization/datasource/datatable/DataTable

I'm using a Java HttpServlet that contains this code (example) to populate the DataTable:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn(new ColumnDescription("uur", ValueType.TEXT, "Uur"));
dataTable.addColumn(new ColumnDescription("aantal", ValueType.NUMBER, "Aantal spellen"));        
try {
    dataTable.addRowFromValues("1", 5, true);
    dataTable.addRowFromValues("2", 9, true);
    dataTable.addRowFromValues("3", 17, true);
} catch (TypeMismatchException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(VerkrijgChartDataServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I also included this to make it return JSON:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

Then with Gson I convert it to a JSON string:

```
new Gson().toJson(dataTable);
```

This returns a string of the format:

```
{
  "columnIndexById" : {"aantal":1, "uur":0},
  "columns" : [
      {"id":"uur","label":"Uur","pattern":"","type":"TEXT"},
      {"id":"aantal","label":"Aantal spellen","pattern":"","type":"NUMBER"}
    ],
  "rows" : [ 
      {"cells":[{"value":{"value":"1"}},{"value":{"value":5.0}}]},
      {"cells":[{"value":{"value":"2"}},{"value":{"value":9.0}}]},
      {"cells":[{"value":{"value":"3"}},{"value":{"value":17.0}}]},
    ],
  "warnings" : []
}
```

But then Google Chart says: 'Table has no colums.'
Google's example JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

Does anyone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to do something else?
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but better late then never. I think I know the answer to your question.

You actually know the answer. In your question, you give a Google Chart JSON example. The JSON string needs to start with

```
{"cols":...}
```

while your JSON string, rendered by gson, starts with

```
{"ColumnIndexById":{...},
 "columns":...
}
```

If you pass a json string to a google DataTable visualisation, then **its structure needs to look exactly like the Google Example**. So instead of "columns", it needs to be "cols".

Answer (score 0):

You can to use the JsonRenderer of API

```
JsonRenderer.renderJsonResponse(
   DataSourceParameters.getDefaultDataSourceParameters(), null, data
)
```